# drag and drop tree with react-redux

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for re-implmentation of this(http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762) in React/Redux. I am able to understant hirarichal view that can be produced by React, presently my needs are to look for Tree like for for each node and it's child, Please let me know if there is some boiler plate code available or for which function/documentation I have to look?

Comment: to use d3Js in React, read [integrating-d3js-visualizations-in-a-react-app](http://nicolashery.com/integrating-d3js-visualizations-in-a-react-app/).

Comment: [React D3Js](https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3) doesn't produce yet this kind of graph. So I think you'll have to use the actual D3JS, called within `componentdidmount()`